# Подскажите, кто из нас правильнее понимает значение сложного предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, времена

Коллеги, у нас тут возник спор, плавно перешедший из юридической плоскости в плоскость русского языка.
Предметом спора является фраза из *Закона*:

> Разрешение на постоянное проживание, выданное иностранцу, может быть
>   аннулировано, если иностранец и члены его семьи, постоянно проживающие
>   в Республике Беларусь, не имеют законного источника получения доходов,
>   обеспечивающих ему и членам его семьи прожиточный минимум,
>   установленный в Республике Беларусь, в течение последних шести
>   месяцев.

На мой взгляд, единственно возможное правильное прочтение этой фразы подразумевает, что подпадающий под ее действие иностранец в течение последних шести месяцев (и по сей день) не имеет источников законного дохода, т.е. если, например, один месяц у него этого дохода не было, а последующие пять месяцев доход был, то под действие этой статьи *Закона* такой иностранец не подпадает.

Мой же оппонент считает, что помимо описанного выше варианта, фразу можно толковать и иным образом: что иностранец должен был обеспечивать прожиточный минимум в течение всех этих шести месяцев, и если хотя бы один из них он этого не делал, то на него распространяется эта статья.

На мой взгляд, в случае подобной трактовки, фраза должна была бы как минимум содержать глагол "имеют" в форме прошедшего времени (выделено полужирным шрифтом):

> Разрешение на постоянное проживание, выданное иностранцу, может быть
>   аннулировано, если иностранец и члены его семьи, постоянно проживающие
>   в Республике Беларусь, не име**ли** законного источника получения доходов,
>   обеспечивающих ему и членам его семьи прожиточный минимум,
>   установленный в Республике Беларусь, в течение последних шести
>   месяцев.

В таком случае можно было бы говорить о возможности двоякого прочтения этой фразы.

В оригинальном же варианте, логика согласования времен в сложном предложении указывает на единственно возможную первую трактовку, иначе фраза была бы просто грамматически не верна.
А как полагаете вы?

Comment: я согласен с вами, смысл заключается в отсутствии дохода в течение  6-ти месяцев подряд, настоящее время указывает на отсутствие по сей день, на английском это было бы выражено презент перфектом has had no income

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я согласен с *вашей* трактовкой, но не считаю, что изменение времени глагола изменило бы смысл (в русском языке прием условного переноса действия в настоящее время достаточно распространен). Для этого понадобилось бы средство посильнее, например:

> ... на протяжении *хотя бы одного из* последних шести месяцев.

Само по себе выражение "*на протяжении*" вместо "*в течение*" мне представляется более убедительным - для исключения попыток иной юридической трактовки этого предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Я согласен с Вашей трактовкой полностью. Если бы хотели сказать, что что-то имело место на протяжении части указанного срока, то употребили бы прошедшее время, иначе никак. В то же время мысль, что странно видеть здесь "в течение", когда следовало бы писать "на протяжении" пришла мне в голову еще до того, как я прочел ответ Alex_ander. Это говорит о том, что данная формулировка закона объективно "хромает".

А то, что ваш оппонент предполагает, законодатель обычно выражает ясно, а не завуалировано, это можно было бы выразить так: "не имеют **постоянного** законного источника получения доходов... в течение последних шести месяцев".

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ! Очень жаль, что невозможно отметить принятыми оба ответа (Ваш и **Alex_ander**), поэтому отмечаю в качестве принятого ответ **Alex_ander**, т.к. он был дан ранее, но хочу лично поблагодарить Вас за дополнительный разбор вопроса.